# Modificar o retorno da função para síncrono

Tags: javascript

Olá, 
Eu preciso modificar esta função para usar o callback como um retorno da função e não como uma nova chamanda de função via callback.

Preciso disso desta forma pois estou criando um método genérico para confirmações de exclusão no sistema já existente. Se eu não conseguir assim, irá me gerar um trabalho imenso de alterações na aplicação.

Estou utilizando a biblioteca JS BootBox e o método é:

```
function Confirm(messageOfConfirmation){
    bootbox.confirm({
        message: messageOfConfirmation,
        buttons: {
            confirm: {
                label: 'Yes',
                className: 'btn-success'
            },
            cancel: {
                label: 'No',
                className: 'btn-danger'
            }
        },
        callback: function (result) {
            functionOfCallback(result);
        }
    });
}
```

E para reforçar e evitar entendimentos de duplicidade na pergunta, segue um exemplo de como pretendo utilizar.

```
function PodeExcluir(){
     if(Confirm("Tem certeza que deseja excluir?"){
        //Chamada de exclusão aqui
    }
}
```

Digo pois, hoje o sistema já utiliza o confirm padrão do JS mas preciso alterar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma simples de resolver isto é usar o seu próprio *callback*.

Exemplo:

```
function Confirm(messageOfConfirmation, functionOfCallback) {
    //nenhum alteração necessária
}

function PodeExcluir(){
     Confirm("Tem certeza que deseja excluir?", function(result) {
         //Chamada de exclusão aqui
     });
}
```

Entenda que, como o código JavaScript é interpretado linearmente no navegador, o uso de elementos para interação com o usuário - com exceção da caixa de confirmação padrão - devem ser de forma assíncrona, isto é, usando, *callbacks*/*listeners, eventos, etc.